# Adobe Kuler to GIMP importer or Converter

Tags: gimp, adobe-kuler

Is there any Ubuntu package for converting from `.ase` to `.gpl` for use with GIMP? A package plug-in, or anything of that sort is appreciated!

Comment: Refer [this](http://www.gimpusers.com/forums/gimp-user/10656-converting-adobe-ase-swatch-files-from-kuler-to-gimp-gpl-swatch-files) article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The only toolkit that did it without trouble is [kuler2gpl](https://www.npmjs.org/package/kuler2gpl) 
Install it (requires [npm](https://www.npmjs.org/)):
`# npm install kuler2gpl`
and to convert everything in folder
`$ kuler2gpl -i /path/to/input/directory`

Answer (score 2):

You can find a GIMP plugin here:
http://registry.gimp.org/node/10325

Comment: where do I drop the file?

Comment: Put it in ~/.gimp2.X/plug-ins and chmod +x it, then restart GIMP

Comment: I get error below:
`Error: Could not import any colors from the file /home/stefano/Desktop/WDesign/tools/Franky Demon.ase.`

Comment: You have python installed and the script is executable?  You could also try http://www.selapa.net/swatchbooker/

Comment: have python installed (python points to 2.7)
Tried other one and did not manage to run it!